# How to access remote machine nodeserver url from my system if both the systems are behind proxy

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

Suppose if my ip address is : 192.65.35.12. In this machine I'm running node server. I can access the webpages by using this url: http://localhost:3000/ in the same machine.

But, if I'm trying to access the node server from a remote machine having the ip 192.65.35.11. It does not work. I used the below url to access the url from the remote machine: http://192.65.35.12:3000/

I'm facing network connectivity issues.

Do, I need to change any settings in node.js for remote access.

Then, how can I access the node server from the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you can access localhost:3000, then type in 192.65.35.12:3000 on same machine. and if you are having problems connecting, then no outside computer going to connect. and you need to adjust your nodejs settings.

if you have server at home, and trying to connect from some place else not at home. you are more likely looking for something like "dynamic ip address" example: http://www.noip.com/  it helps getting past ISP (internet server providers) and your own routers, and publishing your ip address.

if you are dealing with 2 computers in your same house or business and passing through your own router, try changing the 192.65.35.12 to DMZ. basically by passing all router safety, if that happens, you are not opening correct ports on the router. or not setting other setting correctly.

Comment: I'm facing the first problem. I  can accesslocalhost:3000 but not 192.65.35.12:3000 . where do I need to adjust my node.js settings ? can u please help me out ...

Comment: if using notepad++  (not generic notepad that comes with windows).   do a "find in files" on your node app folder, and make sure to search "sub directories" are checked, and search for 3000  (the port number) hopefully a single file comes back. were you can find settings for setting up your app. if 3000 does not work search for localhost or 127.0.0.1 within the files. you may need to input your actual IP address for network adapter on your computer/device for internet and not a loop back IP address which are localhost or 127.0.0.1